# java - Maven assembly plugin build jar with classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a hadoop task as a component of spring-boot application, and I used `maven-assembly-plugin` to compile each file separately.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In the target directory if I start the server with:

```
java -cp target/xx-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.example.MyApplication
```

It occurs an error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

, which was caused by missing classpath. How can I set classpath for the jar? Or do I need to write a script to start my server? In IDE the server can be started with a classpath flag:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 
-noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always 
-javaagent:/home/knh190/idea/idea-IU 171.3780.95/lib/idea_rt.jar=39181:/home/knh190/idea/idea-IU-171.3780.95/bin 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath # list of dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
<configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.my.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Class-Path>your-classpath-here</Class-Path>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When I decompile the jar, dependencies are included but not being found. Do I really need to manually include classpath again?